# Binding to Field of Object in Application Settings

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

In order to control the serialization of a `List<CustomObject>`, I placed that list in a class, eg.:

```
public class SerializableCustomObjectList : IXmlSerializable
{
  public List<CustomObject> CustomObjectList = new List<CustomObject>();
  ...
}

public class CustomObject {...}
```

, an instance of which is stored in the Application Settings.  I have no problem with the serialization/deserialization.  However, when I try to bind the public property, `CustomObjectList`, to a ListBox, nothing happens.

Here's my code:

```
<ListBox Name="CustomObjectListBox">
  <ListBox.ItemsSource>
    <Binding Source="{x:Static p:Settings.Default}"
      Path="SavedCustomObjects.CustomObjectList"/>
  </ListBox.ItemsSource>
  ...
</ListBox>
```

where `SavedCustomObjects` is the instance of SerializableCustomObjectList in the Properties.Settings.Default.

Current behavior is that the ListBox `Items.Count` remains at zero (in the debugger), even when the `SavedCustomObjects.CustomObjectList` is populated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things I can see:

1. You should bind an ItemsControl (such as ListBox) to an ObservableCollection, not a List.
2. You can only bind to properties, not fields (ie use a get/set).
3. The class which is the DataContext should implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and the setter (from point 2) should raise the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: For reference, I found this example that thoroughly illustrates each of the three recommendations that are provided this answer: http://wblum.org/listbind/net3/index.html